# Set boolean attribute according to date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, postgresql

In my app I'm trying to distinguish between active users and those that have "graduated" so to speak. I'm running Rails 4 and the front end is tied into a SPA with AngularJS.

Users have a boolean `active` attribute in the database (Postgres), and I'm trying to automatically set that to be true if the User's selected `end_year` is equal to or greater than the current year (e.g. 2015, 2016, 2017, etc.). Once the User's `end_year` is less than the current year (e.g. 2013, 2014) I would want that boolean to automatically switch to false.

Not sure how I would go about this, or if there is a better way to accomplish the end result of distinguishing between active and "graduated" Users.

For example, in the following code, I'm returning all of the Users in a particular group regardless of their status as active or not-active. What I would want instead is to return all of the Users in a particular group who have not yet "graduated".

```
def self.participants_by_group(group_id, max=5)
  User.find_by_sql(['select users.*
    from users, groups
    where users.group_id = groups.id
    and groups.id = ?
    order by name asc limit ?', group_id, max])
end
```

Comment: is this a one time fix or does this need to happen at N interval?

Comment: @Anthony, ideally this would update the Users' `active` boolean every time the current year changes. And, perhaps every time the User signs in it would check their `end_year` vs. the current year and ensure the boolean is set accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
class User
  # rest of your code

  def graduated?
    end_year >= Date.today.year
  end
end

u1 = User.new(end_year: 2014)
u1.graduated? # => false

u2 = User.new(end_year: 2016)
u2.graduated? # => true
```

For querying *active* `User`'s, you might use something like this:

```
User.where("end_year >= :current_year", {current_year: Date.today.year})
```

Update for `find_by_sql` would be:

```
def self.active_participants_by_group(group_id, max=5)
  User.find_by_sql(['select users.*
    from users, groups
    where users.group_id = groups.id
    and groups.id = ?
    and users.end_year >= ?
    order by name asc limit ?', group_id, Date.today.year, max])
end
```

Comment: would this solution be easy to put to use in these 2 scenarios? 1) `find_by_sql` queries where I'm trying to find the most popular content, but only from active Users, and 2) in the AngularJS front-end, where I would want guests to be able to actively filter/toggle a directory of Users by Active, Not-Active (aka Graduated), or Both.

Comment: Well I'd try to avoid relying on `active` in this case, which seems to be a bit redundant to `end_year`, plus, there is a chance, that `active` might not be updated for some users (because of some error?). But, you could query for those users by: `User.where("end_year >= :current_year",
  {current_year: Date.today.year})`

Comment: I updated the question with some more context that might come in handy as we try to figure this out

Comment: thank you for editing your answer, but how would you convert your addition into SQL compatible with the sample in my question?

Comment: Do you mean how to update your method relying on `find_by_sql`?

Comment: yes, sorry, please forgive me if I'm not using proper terminology, I'm self-taught and pretty new at this

Comment: I can't test proposed solution, because I don't have any project similar to yours, however I added some idea that you might give a chance. Hope that helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72791/discussion-between-andrew-and-pawel-dawczak).

Comment: so it turns out that `end_year` was a string when it should have been an integer, and that was throwing the error. Once I changed the column type, your find_by_sql worked perfectly and I'll mark as correct. Thanks again!